# .htaccess - "hide" a Joomla site in a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have set up a development copy of my Joomla site in a /preview/ subfolder so I can make some changes for client approval before making the /preview site go live (—I will eventually replace the dev site with the original root site after approval).

However, my /preview/ site is getting errors, I think associated with the sh404sef plugin.  Is there a way for the root site to ignore the /preview/ site, either in sh404sef settings or in .htaccess settings?

thanks,
Geoff

Comment: BTW - the error is on the /preview/ site.  It won't load on frontend, getting "500 - JHtmlContent: :prepare not found in file."

Answer (score 0):

There may be some possible reasons making your subfolder installation not to work:

- Check your live_site in your configuration.php to point in the subfolder
- Purge sef404 sef url
- Clear joomla cache
- Clear session table via phpmyadmin
- Make sure that you have connected to the correct database in the configuration.php

If you still get this error, please try:

- to disable .htaccess in the root directory
- replace your .htaccess with the joomla default (without overrides)

I think trying the steps above will help you find where is the problem.